# Is there any sample worklight push notification project with FCM?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, firebase-cloud-messaging

is there any sample worklight push notification project with FCM not GCM? so could you please give me any link where i can download.

Answer (score 2):

The sample for GCM or FCM is the same one. The only thing that differs is the FCM setup steps (which now supersede those for GCM, so essentially you have only FCM).

The setup steps are mentioned here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#google-cloud-messaging--firebase-cloud-messaging

1. Visit the Firebase Console.
2. Create a new project and provide a project name.
3. Click on the Settings “cog wheel” icon and select Project settings.
4. Click the Cloud Messaging tab to generate a Server API Key and a Sender ID and click Save.

As mentioned, the sample is the same sample:

- For Cordova: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/
- For Android: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/android/

> if you are using older releases, the setup steps are the same.

Comment: Thanks @Idan, Actually i am using worklight 7.0,But the documentation is worklight 8.0. Any documentation for worklight 7.0?

Comment: It's the same setup steps. The end result is the same: a key and an ID, that in your case you place in the descriptor file.

Comment: I'm trying to implement FCM in wokrlight 6.2 and I`m getting No devices found